# Node Digitalsignals IIRFilter creates only NaN Values

Tags: node.js, signal-processing

I am planning to use [DSP.js](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/) in the form of node.js [digitalsignals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/digitalsignals) npm module in a project to process signal data. Currently I am trying to perform low pass filtering on my signal. As the processed array data of my signal only contained 'NaN' values after the filter was applied, I tried to apply the filter onto a signal I created with DSP.js Oscillator functions (a simple sine signal actually).

I checked that the sine oscillator generates a sine signal as expected by writing it on the console.log().

But also the processed sine signal results into NaN values after applying the IIRFilter.

My code for testing is as follows:

```
var dsp = require('digitalsignals');
var buffer = [];

var osc = new dsp.Oscillator(dsp.SINEWAVE, 440, 1, 2048, 22050);
osc.generate();
buffer = osc.signal;
console.log(buffer); // shows correct sine signal array

var filter = new dsp.IIRFilter(dsp.LOWPASS, 200, 44100);
filter.process(buffer);
console.log(buffer); // shows only NaN
```

The code is basically copy/paste of corban brook's github site.

Comment: Can you show the filter coefficients of your filter?

Comment: Sorry, as DSP.js is just an implementation of IIRFilters I am using, I actually don't know which coefficients are used. I also do not know how this is relevant to this specific JavaScript library Problem. I'm afraid the library is simply buggy or even not usable in ist current state of development.and wanted to know if others know a workaround as it is an official node npm package where even example code is not working as it seems.

Comment: There is the possibility that a 200 Hz low pass IIR at 44.1 kHz sampling rate, can be unstable, particularly for a  high filter order. Maybe its not a bug, but specific to the parameters you used.  Do you still get NaNs when you change the 200 Hz lowpass frequency to 2 kHz?

Comment: ok, didn't know that ...seems like a very good hint. Unfortunately it didn't help, I changed freq cutoff to 2khz and also some other values (5khz ...), but everytime I get NaNs again. Fastest way to test this is to use Cloud9 (https://ide.c9.io/) and copy/past the example from above. Would like to share, but Cloud9 doesn't allow this for anonymous users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be tested e.g. here: https://tonicdev.com/npm/digitalsignals, where you can just cut and paste, no account required.

They actually posted their example wrong, you need to call the filter e.g. like this:

```
var filter = new dsp.IIRFilter(dsp.LOWPASS, 200,1,44100);
```

If you look in dsp.js https://github.com/zewemli/dsp.js/blob/master/dsp.js you will find a definition somewhere like this:

```
var IIRFilter = DSP.IIRFilter = function(type, cutoff, resonance, sampleRate)
```

So you were essentially missing the resonance parameter in your call.

Comment: Easy as that... thank you very much for that hint. I should definitely read more function head definitions and less documentation ;) Knowing that it works now perfectly